# RestKit - handling nesting of attributes

Tags: json, mapping, xcode4.2, restkit, nested

I have downloaded the latest RestKit version 0.9.3 from github and 
noticed that the method mapFromKeyPath: toAttribute: has been removed 
from RKObjectMapping. The method is used to nest attributes in the 
Json body of the message.

Is there a replacement method or another way 
of nesting attributes without the mapFromKeyPath method?

Comment: Have you whatched these methods ? :
`– mapKeyPath:toAttribute:`
And
`– mappingForKeyPath:`

Comment: And this one for nested attribute : `– mapKeyPath:toRelationship:withMapping:`

Comment: I tried using mapKeyPath:toAttribute but it didnt work in nesting the attribute. From my understanding, mapKeyPath:toRelationship:withMapping: requires two separate objects. Is it possible to do a nested attribute with just one object?

Comment: You're right it is for separated objects. But what happens if you are using mapFromKeyPath ? Because all exemples use this method ...

Comment: ah mapFromKeyPath no longer exists in the latest version of RestKit and its API. I believe the creators removed it from the build for some reason. Some of the examples are outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the **new** object mapping documentation. You can find it at [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md). Object mapping is very different now. The old docs (and tutorials) that are scattered about the web don't work anymore.

Comment: I did read that documentation. However restkit v 0.9.3 no longer includes mapFromKeyPath. Blake suggested that I revert to the previous version, but I have worked around the issue by using relationship mapping instead

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was trying so say, sorry for being oblique about it. You need to use mapping now.